# C++/CLI - Is it possible to check a POP3 email account and receive messages?

Tags: c++, email, command-line-interface, pop3

Is it possible to check a POP3 email account and receive messages in C++/CLI? If so, how would this be done? I'm quite new to this, so if anyone who answers could do so in layman's terms, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which one is it? C++ or CLI? If you're after C++, there are plenty of pop3 libraries available. Google is your friend. If you want a good CLI one, try fetchmail. It can poll from multiple sources and has a lot of delivery options.

Comment: Okay, I've downloaded fetchmail. What do I do with it? I've read the install file but I'm working on windows. Sorry to be a pain, but I really don't know what to do with it.